# Unable to set cuctom html5 validation message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to use browser validation messaging. I am not able to define a custom message when 2 fields are NOT identical.

My situation is that i have to test when the field IS valid, so i used jquery `on.blur` to test, but for some reason, the message is empty.

Try entering 2 valid but different email addresses. The expected result is supposed to be "Test why not working" has a browser message.

[Working jsFiddle of my situation](http://jsfiddle.net/26veA/1/)

HTML:

```
<form id="newsletter_form" class="form" role="form" name="newsletter_form" method="post" action="/" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" value="" maxlength="250" placeholder="email" aria-required="true" required="required" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="confirm_email" id="confirm_email" value="" maxlength="250" placeholder="confirm email" aria-required="true" required="required" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn submit btn-default" value="submmit!" />
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('form #email').on('change invalid', function () {
    var field = $(this).get(0);
    field.setCustomValidity('');
    if (!field.validity.valid) {
        field.setCustomValidity("custom email invalid");
    }
});


/* THIS IS MY BUGGY ONE */
$('form #confirm_email').on('blur valid', function () {
    var field = $(this).get(0);
    field.setCustomValidity('');
    if ($("#email").val() != $("#confirm_email").val()) {
        /* i tried setting the field to invalid, nothing */
        //field.validity.invalid;
        //alert('s');
        field.setCustomValidity("test why not working");
    }
});

$('form #confirm_email').on('change invalid', function () {
    var field = $(this).get(0);
    field.setCustomValidity('');
    if (!field.validity.valid) {
        field.setCustomValidity("custom error message");
    }
});
```

I tried jquery.on(change valid  .. and so on, i get the `alert()` bot not the changed text.

Any help will be appreciated, i am getting bored of this 'bug'?

Comment: I think it would be much simplier to use the jquery plugin validation (http://jqueryvalidation.org) instead of struggling with browser messages, which could be different from browser to browser. What works e. g. in IE is not meant to work also in Opera. With my suggested method you can cover up all browsers with the same code. With this plugin you can also set your own messages by defining your own validator rule.

Comment: Hi @alpham8 and thanks for your input, actually it is conforming has i want ie9+ and cross-modern-brower overrided support by h5f javascript library. the decision is not mine, i just HAVE to do with this.

Comment: As a side note, browser validation is so kind as to only show you one validation error at a time. While I understand it is not your decision, it is still an argument for whoever is making that call. Browser validation just isn't there yet.

Comment: Hi @KaiQing, i am not actually in a mood to discuss designers decisions, i just wanna go home and get some rest, but for doing so, i need to set the custom text in the browser validation output. I did it already but am unable to achieve that particular test with identical fields.

Comment: Ok, I don´t know anything about the lib h5f. Sorry, but I am out. But I think as mentiod by Kai Qing you can only show one error message at the same time. In other words that means to do it in the old school style: Cancel the validation on the first error! I mean an if-else if-else if-else construct. The else case should be then if validation was passed. So, you can use the browser messages. But I would reccommend you to find a way to get the same error message string for each browser. If this is possible, you will be fine out with only a few lines of code ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but for some reason, the message is empty.

That is because you are explicitly setting it to be empty:

> ```
> field.setCustomValidity('');
> ```

in your "custom error message" handler that is used to grump about the invalid email. That handler is executed after the `'blur valid'`, and will always reset what happened before. You can try it by uncommenting above line.

> Any help will be appreciated

Check both reasons in the same handler:

```
$('form #confirm_email').on('change valid invalid', function () {
    // var field = $(this).get(0); -- don't do this!!! field = this.

    this.setCustomValidity('');
    if (!this.validity.valid) {
        this.setCustomValidity("custom message for standard errors");
    } else if ($("#email").val() != this.value) {
        this.setCustomValidity("test now working");
    }
});
```

([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26veA/7/))

Comment: héhé ... testing it now. Tested it ... and i can go home. Man, thankyou for your refresing answer. I did not think about the blur and change .. and jquery processing.

Comment: What do this means ?? : better: field.validity.typeMismatch // to check for email pattern

Comment: I figured you might only want to check for the email correctness there, then you could've used a more specific property of the `validity` object. Not relevant for the question and probably guessed wrong, wasn't it?

Comment: Well, you quite guessed right, but no, i didn't want to validate furthermore.